# Is this enough to stop javascript bots from getting textarea content?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, bots

Some bots usually get the textarea content by using `document.getElementById("textAreaID").value`

What I do is generate a random ID for every page refresh, ie:

```
<textarea id="random83721045">
</textarea>
```

Is there a way a javascript bot can bypass this random ID? And if so, is there a way to block this without using captcha?

Comment: "Bots usually get the textarea content by using..." ***nope***. Expecting anything to be consistent with malicious people is beyond naive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bot can get your textareas in any number of ways. If they want to use jquery, they can very easily target form elements by name.

Anti-spam measures are only effective on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Bots usually are not interested in textarea contents. They prefer writing their stuff into the fields and try a successful submit of a form. There are better ways to protect your forms, like a Captcha, or Akismet.

Comment: I am not interested in the form, actually. I just need to avoid bots to get textarea content

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to keep out spammers? Forget it, they are smarter than that. Their bots are built to work on as many websites as possible, so they don't rely on id's to find out which text area does what. I suspect many bots use heuristics, like nearby text strings or sizes of elements, to find out which text input does what.